# Java 8: Syntax for Implementing java.util.function.Function as a Lambda Expression

Tags: java, syntax, lambda, java-8

I'm having trouble with Java 8's syntax for lambda expressions, I can't seem to create one on the fly in one line. The following code works,

```
Function<Integer, Integer> increment = (x) -> (x + 1);
doStuff(increment);
```

but the following lines do not

```
doStuff((x) -> (x + 1));
doStuff(Function (x) -> (x + 1));
doStuff(new Function (x) -> (x + 1));
doStuff(Function<Integer, Integer> (x) -> (x + 1));
doStuff(new Function(Integer, Integer> (x) -> (x + 1));
doStuff(new Function<Integer, Integer>(x -> {x + 1;}));
```

and I'm not quite sure what else I can try. I certainly don't want to use

```
doStuff(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer x){
        return x + 1;
    }
});
```

so what else is there? I've looked through a bunch of questions on lambda expression syntax and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply

```
doStuff((x) -> (x + 1));
```

You had

```
Function<Integer, Integer> increment = (x) -> (x + 1);
doStuff(increment);
```

So just replace it with the right hand side of `=` (generally).

```
(x) -> (x + 1)
```

If `doStuff`'s single parameter is not of type `Function<Integer, Integer>`, you'll need a target functional interface type

```
doStuff((Function<Integer,Integer>) (x) -> (x + 1));
```

Your method was using a raw `Function` type. Read

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Does not work either, `doStuff` requires a `Function`.

Comment: @user3002473 Please explain what errors you are getting. Please give the signature of `doStuff`.

Comment: When I leave is as `(x) -> (x + 1)`, it gives me the error `bad operand types for binary operator '+'`. If I put `(Integer x) -> (x + 1)`, it says `no suitable method found for doStuff((int x)->(x + 1))`.

Comment: The signature of `doStuff` is `doStuff(Function function)`.

Comment: @user3002473 It's raw. Parameterize it as `Function<Integer, Integer>` or do what I added in my most recent edit.