# A function that takes in a wildcard list and a Function?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a method that takes in a wildcard list, but also takes in an implementation of `java.util.function.Function` that takes in an element of the same type the list contains and returns a `String`. To do this, I have two ideas in mind but neither of them are satisfactory.

Method 1: Making the method generic.

```
public <T> void method(List<T> list, Function<T, String> function){
    ...
}
```

Method 2: Making the `Function`'s first type a wildcard?

```
public void method(List<?> list, Function<?, String> function){
    ...
}
```

I don't like method 1, and I'm not even sure if method 2 works because sometimes I get weird errors like the following:

```
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to CAP#1
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Is there another way I can create a method like this without leaving the `Function` argument raw?

Comment: In my opinion, there's no way around using the generic version of your method. If you use wildcards (and didn't get that "incompatible types" error), both the contents of the list and the accepted type of the given function can be arbitrary, so even classes you cant cast. Why do you not like the generic version?

Comment: @flashdrive2049 It's just a personal preference, I've never liked the syntax for calling generic methods, and in this specific method I'm trying to implement it would only make it even less eloquent. If it's the only thing I can do though, then I can live with it.

Comment: I would make an effort to get used to the syntax. It's very useful and not defining the type is error prone and the result is unnecessary casting.

Comment: @user3002473 I really don't know any other way to achieve what you're trying to do except a generic method. If I get a bit more context though, I might be able to find a solution without generics.

Comment: @user3002473 Is this question probably connected to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338158/)?

Comment: @flashdrive2049 Yes indeed! Here's the story; I wrote a bunch of code at a time when I couldn't compile it to ensure it was correct, so now (a few days later) I'm looking at the code in an environment where I can compile it and there are a lot of places where I call this `method` (among others) and they all have a raw `Function` parameter.

Comment: @user3002473 If you want to call your ```method``` with a lambda expression, try something like ```method(new ArrayList<Foo>(), (Foo foo) -> (foo.methodReturnsString()));```. Even with that, you won't be able to go around generics.

Comment: @flashdrive2049 What would the signature for `method` be?

Comment: Can you clarify your first paragraph? When you say _wildcard list_, do you `List<?>`? If that's what you have, how can you know what it contains in order to pass a `Function` that operates on that type?

Comment: @user3002473 The first option you showed above. ```public <T> void method(List<T>, Function<T, String>)```

Comment: @flashdrive2049 That doesn't work unfortunately, unless I had a target interface for the lambda expression; `method(new ArrayList<Foo>(), (Function<Foo, String>) (Foo foo) -> (foo.methodReturnsString()));`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's exactly what I'm confused about! I don't always know what the list will contain, but I do know that the `Function` I pass in will always have the same first parameter as the list, so I'm not sure how to go about writing the signature for such a method.

Comment: @user3002473 I guess I'll try to phrase an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the *wildcast* version of your method

```java
public void method(List<?> list, Function<?, String> function)
```

is out of the question, because - as you already noticed - using a wildcast as a variable's type is not possible.

There's one other way that does *not* use generic type arguments. You could try to use

```java
public void method(List<Object> list, Function<Object, String> function)
```

as your method's signature if you really want to use a list containing instances of multiple classes as `list`.

However, if you only want to allow one type of elements, you definitely have to use generics, so your method would have to look like you already showed in your question:

```java
public <T> void method(List<T> list, Function<T, String> function)
```

If your problem is *how to call* your method in case you're using generics, that's pretty simple. Say, you've got a `List<Integer> list`. If you then call `method(list,...)`, the generic type of `list` automatically determines the first type parameter of `function`, in this case `function` would have to be an instance of `Function<Integer, String>`. Since you want to use a lambda expression for calling the method, something like

```java
method(list, (Integer i) -> (String.valueOf(i)));
```

would be perfectly correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help! My assumption is that in my previous question, that lambda syntax didn't work because `Function` was a raw argument.

Comment: @flashdrive2049 give you one for covering java 8

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but I think the issue is here:

```
public void method(List<?> list, Function<?, String> function){
    ...
}
```

You are probably making the assumption that both wild cards in the signature are of the same type.  Try something like this:

```
public <T> void method(List<T> list, Function<T, String> function){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I guess you wrote exactly the same as the OP asked.

Comment: I did have that in mind (it's in the question itself), but for reasons specific to the actual `method` I'm trying to create, making it generic just wouldn't be an elegant solution, so I'm looking for something else.

Comment: I think that's as good as it gets as far as generics go. The only other alternative it to define a strict type.

Comment: @flashdrive2049 Oh... yeah, I guess I did... :P